# How do I reload table data in viewWillAppear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I know there has to be a simple solution for this.  I want to get my `tableView` to update every time that `viewWillAppear` would run.  How do I call it from within the `viewWillAppear` method, and get it to run as often as it needs to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `[tableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 1):

[self.tableview reloadData];

use it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the table.

Just put this line in `viewWillAppear:`

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

**reloadData: Reloads the rows and sections of the receiver.**
-Courtesy : Apple Documentation.